# Unable to delete file: androidx.databinding.library.baseAdapters--setter_store.json

Tags: kotlin, android-databinding

What is this error with databinding in Kotlin + Android Studio?

```
> Configure project :app
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

> Task :clean
> Task :app:clean FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:clean'.
> Unable to delete file: C:\MyFolder\app\build\intermediates\data_binding_dependency_artifacts\debug\dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug\out\androidx.databinding.library.baseAdapters--setter_store.json
```

Ending Process in Windows resource monitor, gradlew clean, or invalidating cache and restarting clears it but it creeps right back on the second build/clean attempt.

My app build.gradle

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
...
}
```

My project build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$gradle_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}
```

Comment: Sometime, JVM does not release the resources when your previous build throws exception. Try `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart`, it should work most of the time. If it still not work, restart the computer.